# Can you hit an exact number on a bounded number line

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

My first question here. I am not sure if it belongs here or not.

If I were to place a number line, e.g. [0,4], and attempt to shoot at it, while aiming for a specific number. Would I be able to actually hit that number?

The question may sound absurd, but the point I am trying to make or understand is as following:

Say, I am aiming for a rational number, e.g. **1**. I aim and throw multiple times. How would I with absolute certainty be able to determine, that I have actually managed to hit **1**, and not simply some number in e.g. [$1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon$]?

Now, let's say I attempt another number. This time an irrational number, e.g. **$\pi$**. Is it even possible to hit it? Aren't irrational numbers by definition numbers with never ending digits. Meaning, if I were to hit a number, in this case **$\pi$**, wouldn't it in fact be an approximation to **$\pi$**, as I can't actually "reach" that last digit. Meaning, I will always be able to find a smaller bound than [$\pi - \epsilon,\pi + \epsilon$], but never actually knowing if I have reached **$\pi$**?

Comment: There are infinitely many points on any line segment, no matter how short and there are infinitely many real numbers in any interval, [a, b], no matter how close together a and b are.  Taking every point to be "equally likely", the probability of hitting a given single point on a line segment is  0.  You will have to specify some interval or collection of intervals in a given interval in order to have a non-zero probability.

Comment: Can you clarify this: '''You will have to specify some interval or collection of intervals in a given interval in order to have a non-zero probability.'''

Comment: How well can you aim?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist always very well, but never well enough!

Comment: I can aim within a small enough bound. But is that sufficient?

Comment: Ponder this: you can always get more accurate to a decimal representation of any number by adding an additional decimal place. Since you can add infinitely many decimal places (unless you're saying otherwise), you're always going to be off by just _that_ much when you decide to stop measuring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question that has no easy answer.

The probability that you hit any particular number - rational or not, is $0$. The probability that you hit some rational number is also $0$, so the probability that you hit an irrational number is $1$. This has nothing to do with the difficulty of expressing an irrational number as a decimal fraction.

Proving these things rigorously depends on the careful definition of  probability. That definition begins with the assertion that the probability of a finite interval is its length, divided by the length of the interval you are choosing from (in your case, $4$).

It's even harder to think about probability when you are choosing a point from the whole number line rather than from a bounded interval.

Your question asks about "aiming", not directly about probability. Then the answer really depends on how well you can aim. If perfectly, then you can hit any number you aim for with probability $1$. If you can get withing $\epsilon$ repeatedly you can calculate the number of tries needed to get as close as you like. You won't be able to hit your target for sure, whether it's rational or not.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the question the asnwear is no. The probability to select a number from an interval is always 0. Maybe you want to be more specific in the part "aim for an specific number"

Comment: By aiming, I mean to imply that I select one of the infinite many numbers on the real number line, and try to see my (dart) bullet actually (lands on) hits that number.

Comment: If the head of the dart is just a point no matter how small your interval is, the chance of hiting your desire number is 0, if the head is an interval $I$ then the probability to hit you number is $I$ over the whole interval you are confident your dart is going to land. Maybe that's what you meant by "aim" the interval of confidence

Comment: In physical sense, the pointy end of a real bullet or a dart would actually encompass a certain diameter. However, in this hypothetical case, I am rather considering the pointy end to be infinitesimal.